# Facebook Login API works on localhost but doesn't work on hosting server

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to make a login system with facebook. It is working fine on localhost but when I put it online it doesn't work. I've changed the link of url in the settings to but it doesn't work.

When I click on login, it goes to facebook and when I allow it it goes to the next page but it gets redirected due to this.

```
if(!$fbuser){
    $fbuser = null;
        header('Location: ../index.php');
}
```

This is my index.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
include_once("../config.php");
include("admin001.php");
//destroy facebook session if user clicks reset
if(!$fbuser){
    $fbuser = null;
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>$homeurl,'scope'=>$fbPermissions));
        header('Location: ../index.php');
}
else{
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,email,gender,locale,picture,link');


    if(!empty($user_profile))
    {
        $image_url = $user_profile['picture']['data']['url'];
        $f_name = $user_profile['first_name'];
        $l_name = $user_profile['last_name'];
        $email = $user_profile['email'];
        $gender = $user_profile['gender'];
        $name = $user_profile['name'];
        $fblink = $user_profile['link'];
        $fbid = $user_profile['id'];
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['fbid']=$fbid;
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: ../index.php');
    }
}

?>
```

This is my config.php

```
<?php
include_once("inc/facebook.php"); //include facebook SDK
######### Facebook API Configuration ##########
$appId = '***'; //Facebook App ID
$appSecret = '***'; // Facebook App Secret
$homeurl = 'http://isaurav.net/test/index.php';  //return to home
$fbPermissions = 'email';  //Required facebook permissions

//Call Facebook API
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $appId,
  'secret' => $appSecret

));
$fbuser = $facebook->getUser();
?>
```

Comment: Have you whitelisted the urls on facebook?

Comment: How am I supposed to do that ?

Comment: Go to https://developers.facebook.com/ and open the settings for your app. Under facebook login you can whiteliste different domains.

Comment: By the way...I'am getting the result from facebook like.... [link](http://isaurav.net/test/index.php?code=AQDuuXAXKT52H0_uv-BeOUxm8VIC_SdlXpFufSFt82P3DBFfCYn8rusyxMYE0W55upqrRks8kyMm5WFKHfb54yR6zJlEtRkYC9vwNO2NOz_dvu--Q0iNYF0AEu2pqBoeUIWS647WbSsGwWoUxxPwC4TgylaEbDnyKMv28-l4eEDseXKVVLtLd0jVN1ONOofigwvvci3T01HJZcuoJwySXKjMXMnZ6PZJZXqCSV_TDG78nFucujVnTzSwUn5ZWyqfR0uFJuWbBBxXIwEZUtzlAuZGNep2NmqGSqvF5biPxh8lmMl9sg4yvJpDcWFB26WhG89NV6mSie4I8PgqgCqvBKzf&state=af4e59ad7ec5789cab8f1b35291b0dc7#_=_)